# Using Prefetch Filter with typeahead.js (Using basic options)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I am using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). I am using the prefetch options and need to parse the returned data. It's not throwing an error; it's not doing much of anything. I've looked for examples but none of them use the Prefetch Filter option.

[Link to the prefetch documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#prefetch)

My code (that does not work but throws no errors):

```
$('#autocomplete').typeahead('destroy').typeahead( {                                
    name: 'organizations',
    prefetch: {
        url: 'jsoncall',
        filter: function() {
                        // Blatant hardcoded return value
                        return ['test-a','test-b','test'c];
                      }
        }
    }
);
```

My HTML:

```
<input id="autocomplete" class="large-12" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Enter school name">
```

My Confusion:

```
0________0
```

Comment: This has helped...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321544/twitters-bootstrap-typeahead-setup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the returned data through the `filter` function which then parses the data to your liking.  So in your example above, you would do something like this:

```
$('#autocomplete').typeahead({                                
    name: 'organizations',
    prefetch: 
            {
        url: 'jsoncall',
        filter: function(data){
               // filter the returned data
               return [data.movies[0].title, data.movies[1].title, data.movies[2].title];
        }
    }
}
);
```

The example above would work if your returned data set was a JSON object that looked something like this:

```
movies: [{id:12865, title:Kill Bill: Volume 1, year:2003, mpaa_rating:R, runtime:111,…},…]
0: {id:12865, title:Kill Bill: Volume 1, year:2003, mpaa_rating:R, runtime:111,…}
1: {id:12862, title:Kill Bill, Volume 2, year:2004, mpaa_rating:R, runtime:137,…}
2: {id:771237417, title:Kill Bill: The Whole Bloody Affair, year:2011,     mpaa_rating:Unrated, runtime:,…}
3: {id:770998578, title:Angel of Death: Killer Nurse: A Bill Kurtis Special Report, year:2006,…}
4: {id:771352617, title:Kedi Billa Killadi Ranga, year:2013, mpaa_rating:Unrated, runtime:145,…}
total: 5
```