# Map typeahead suggestions after they are fetched

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am using the last twitter typeahead.

```
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {url:'/xxx?text=%QUERY',
            ajax:{
                type : 'post',
                dataType : 'json'
            }
        }
    });
    suggestions.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        displayKey: 'id',
        source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: '<p style="width:50%;margin:auto;">No result</p>',
            suggestion: function(object){
                    var str = ['<p>',
                        object.id,
                        '</p><a class="btn btn-info btn-small" href="item.html?id="',
                        object.id,
                        '>Open</a>'].join('');

                    return str;
                }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I recieve 5 objects of type

```
{
id: 0,
field: '', 
value: ''
}
```

All 5 objects have the same id and therefore are **fields of one result** and should be put into **one suggestion**. Typeahead treats them as **separate suggestions** which **I don't want**.

How do I map over the results of the ajax call, transform it and pass the result back to typeahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [filter(parsedResponse)](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote) to do the parsing of the response yourself. You can see an example (to an unrelated answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321544/twitters-bootstrap-typeahead-setup).